# C++ Template argument changes Reference to Pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

Maybe I didn't know how to search, but it's fact that I couldn't find anyone talking about this.

I have struct that has a *non-type* argument that depends on a *type* argument.

```
template<
    typename SpecType,
    SpecType NonType >
struct Struct
//...
```

When `SpecType` is a reference to a pointer (`const char *&`, for example) `NonType` behaves as if it is the address of the actual specialized argument, and not a reference.
More surprising is that if I explicitly cast `NonType` to `SpecType`, everything works as expected!

[IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/non-type_template_parameters.htm) says something about conversion to pointer of arrays and functions, but I don't understand it as related to my doubt.

When I create structs that have no embedded template types (`S1` and `S2`) the same thing does ot happen.

Of course I can change it to:

```
template<
    typename SpecType,
    SpecType &NonType >
```

but it won't explain what I see.
Can anyone please give a deep (or dumb, if it is my stupidness) explanation?

---

The following example is a bit extense, but looking at its output I think my problem will be more clear:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <typeinfo>

using namespace std;


void    f1( const char **p )
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "f1( const char **p ): p = \"" << p << "\"" << endl;
}

void    f1( const char *p )
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "f1( const char *p ): p = \"" << p << "\"" << endl;
}

void    f1( const int **p )
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "f1( const int **p ): p = \"" << p << "\"" << endl;
}

void    f1( const int *p )
{
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "f1( const int *p ): p = \"" << p << "\"" << endl;
}

template<
    typename SpecType,
    SpecType NonType >
struct Struct
{
    void    f( )
    {
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "SpecType is " << typeid( SpecType ).name( ) << endl;
        cout << "NonType is " << typeid( NonType ).name( ) << endl;
        cout << "NonType = \"" << NonType << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "( SpecType )NonType = \"" << ( SpecType )NonType << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "*NonType = \"" << *NonType << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "*NonType[ 0 ] = \"" << **NonType << "\"" << endl;

        f1( NonType );
    }
};

template< const char *&P >
struct  S1
{
    void    f( )
    {
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "&P = \"" << &P << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "P = \"" << P << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "*P = \"" << *P << "\"" << endl;

        f1( P );
    }
};

template< const char **P >
struct  S2
{
    void    f( )
    {
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "P = \"" << P << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "*P = \"" << *P << "\"" << endl;
        cout << "*P[ 0 ] = \"" << **P << "\"" << endl;

        f1( P );
    }
};

const char * const_pname    = "name";

const int   pint[]  = { 42, 51 };
const int   *const_pint = pint;

int main( )
{
    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "const_pname = " << const_pname << endl;
    cout << "@const_pname = 0x" << hex << ( unsigned long )const_pname << dec << endl;
    cout << "&const_pname = 0x" << hex << ( unsigned long )&const_pname << dec << endl;

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "Struct< const char *&, const_pname >   constpTtname" << endl;
    Struct< const char *&, const_pname >    constpTtname;
    constpTtname.f( );

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "Struct< const int *&, const_pint > constpTtint" << endl;
    Struct< const int *&, const_pint >  constpTtint;
    constpTtint.f( );

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "S1< const_pname >  s1" << endl;
    S1< const_pname >   s1;
    s1.f( );

    cout << "=============================================" << endl;
    cout << "S2< &const_pname > s2" << endl;
    S2< &const_pname >  s2;
    s2.f( );

    return  0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./nontype_mutant
=============================================
const_pname = name
@const_pname = x401624                                                                   
&const_pname = 0x601e18                                                                   
=============================================                                             
Struct< const char *&, const_pname >    constpTtname                                      
---------------------------------------------                                             
SpecType is PKc                                                                           
NonType is PKc                                                                            
NonType = "$@"                                                                            
( SpecType )NonType = "name"                                                              
*NonType = "name"                                                                         
*NonType[ 0 ] = "n"                                                                       
---------------------------------------------                                             
f1( const char *p ): p = "$@"                                                             
=============================================                                             
Struct< const int *&, const_pint >      constpTtint                                       
---------------------------------------------                                             
SpecType is PKi                                                                           
NonType is PKi                                                                            
NonType = "0x601e20"                                                                      
( SpecType )NonType = "0x4017a8"                                                          
*NonType = "0x4017a8"                                                                     
*NonType[ 0 ] = "42"                                                                      
---------------------------------------------                                             
f1( const int *p ): p = "0x601e20"                                                        
=============================================                                             
S1< const_pname >       s1
---------------------------------------------
&P = "0x601e18"
P = "name"
*P = "n"
---------------------------------------------
f1( const char *p ): p = "name"
=============================================
S2< &const_pname >      s2
---------------------------------------------
P = "0x601e18"
*P = "name"
*P[ 0 ] = "n"
---------------------------------------------
f1( const char **p ): p = "0x601e18"
```

Comment: @Ben Voigt: g++ (GCC) 4.4.5 20101112 (Red Hat 4.4.5-2) and g++ (GCC) 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to compile your code using three compilers and two of them have very similar behavior giving the following message (approximately):

```
test.cpp:44:41: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
        cout << "*NonType[ 0 ] = \"" << **NonType << "\"" << endl;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:93:18: note: in instantiation of member function 'Struct<const char *&, const_pname>::f' requested here
    constpTtname.f( );
                 ^
test.cpp:44:41: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
        cout << "*NonType[ 0 ] = \"" << **NonType << "\"" << endl;
                                        ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:98:17: note: in instantiation of member function 'Struct<const int *&, const_pint>::f' requested here
    constpTtint.f( );
                ^
2 errors generated.
```

The error message seems correct and self evident to me.  This was the result of using clang.  Comeau's EDG based compiler was the other one to give a message very similar to this.

g++ compiled it (I believe incorrectly) and gave an output similar to that you report.

Comment: "$ g++ -Wall nontype_mutant.cpp -o nontype_mutant" gives me no error. I recopied, recompiled and rerun the example from my own post to be sure I've not done anything wrong. You can safely comment line 44 and the related problem will still be there. Please watch out in my post that the problem is in reference acting like a pointer, not in an indirection compile error.