# c++ strange template specialization on inner variable

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

Consider the following code:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <typeinfo>
#include    <cstring>
#include    <cstdlib>

static void random_string( char *s, const int len )
{
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
        s[ i ] = alphanum[ rand( ) % ( sizeof( alphanum ) - 1 ) ];

    s[ len ] = 0;
}

template< typename Type, int Length >
void    info( Type ( &var )[ Length ] )
{
    std::cout << "->    Type is " << typeid( var ).name( ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Pointer size:   " << sizeof( Type * ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Number of elements: " << Length << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Size of each element:   " << sizeof( Type ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    contents: \"" << var << "\"." << std::endl;
}


template< typename SourceType, int SourceLength, typename TargetType, int TargetLength >
void    func( TargetType ( &target )[ TargetLength ] )
{
    SourceType  source[ SourceLength ];

    random_string( ( char * )source, SourceLength - 1 );

    std::cout << "-= source =-" << std::endl;
    info( source );

    std::cout << "-= target =-" << std::endl;
    info( target );

    std::memcpy( target, source,
            ( SourceLength < TargetLength ? SourceLength : TargetLength ) );
}

int main( )
{
    typedef char    char16[ 16 ];
    typedef char    char64[ 64 ];

    char16  c16 = "16 bytes chars.";
    char64  c64 = "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...";

    std::cout << "c16 = \"" << c16 << "\"." << std::endl;
    func< char64, sizeof( char64 ) >( c16 );
    std::cout << "c16 = \"" << c16 << "\"." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c64 = \"" << c64 << "\"." << std::endl;
    func< char16, sizeof( char16 ) >( c64 );
    std::cout << "c64 = \"" << c64 << "\"." << std::endl;

    return  0;
}
```

And this output:

```
> g++ -Wall -g3 array_conversions.cpp -o array_conversions
> ./array_inner_type
c16 = "16 bytes chars.".
-= source =-
->      Type is A64_A64_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     64
->      Size of each element:   64
->      contents: "0x7fff8b913380".
-= target =-
->      Type is A16_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     16
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "16 bytes chars.".
c16 = "fa37JncCHryDsbza".
c64 = "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...".
-= source =-
->      Type is A16_A16_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     16
->      Size of each element:   16
->      contents: "0x7fff8b914280".
-= target =-
->      Type is A64_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     64
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...".
c64 = "Z2nOXpPIhMFSv8k".
```

As we can see, the understanding of what `SourceType source[ SourceLength ]` is for me and GCC is not the same.

I expected `SourceType source[ SourceLength ]` to be of type `char64` ("A64_c"), but GCC tells me it is "A64_A64_c" and acts as if it was an *array of `char64`* or something like.

Strangely it only happens to the local `source` variable. The `target` function parameter is correctly interpreted.

What I am missing?
Is there any misunderstanding in my code?

I feel this problem is related to this one [C++ Template argument changes Reference to Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316262/c-template-argument-changes-reference-to-pointer), posted by myself almost one year ago, but this question had no answer anyhow, so now I beg you please for any help.

Really thanks.

Comment: you wrote too much code, please be more concise by removing uninteresting parts from the code.

Answer (score 1):

`c16` has type `char[16]`

`func< char64, sizeof( char64 ) >( c16 )` instantiates `func` with

```
SourceType == char64 == char[64]
SourceLength == sizeof( char64 ) == 64
TargetType == char
TargetLength == 16
```

This means that `target` has type `char (&)[16]` and `source` has type `char[64][64]`.

This explains why `target` is an array of `char`, and `source` is an array of arrays of `char`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, sorry..

It was really my fault.
The solution, in fact, is really simpler than what I was trying to do.
I've just seen it thanks to the words of a friend.

Unfortunately he is not logged in, so I'll simply paste a working version of the same code:

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <typeinfo>
#include    <cstring>
#include    <cstdlib>


static void random_string( char *s, const int len )
{
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for ( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
        s[ i ] = alphanum[ rand( ) % ( sizeof( alphanum ) - 1 ) ];

    s[ len ] = 0;
}

template< typename Type, int Length >
void    info( Type ( &var )[ Length ] )
{
    std::cout << "->    Type is " << typeid( var ).name( ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Pointer size:   " << sizeof( Type * ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Number of elements: " << Length << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    Size of each element:   " << sizeof( Type ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "->    contents: \"" << var << "\"." << std::endl;
}


template< typename SourceType, typename TargetType >
void    func( TargetType ( &target ) )
{
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    SourceType  source;

    random_string( ( char * )source, sizeof( SourceType ) - 1 );

    std::cout << "-= source =-" << std::endl;
    info( source );

    std::cout << "-= target =-" << std::endl;
    info( target );

    std::memcpy( target, source,
            ( sizeof( SourceType ) < sizeof( TargetType ) ?
                sizeof( SourceType ) : sizeof( TargetType ) ) );
}


int main( )
{
    typedef char    char16[ 16 ];
    typedef char    char64[ 64 ];

    char16  c16 = "16 bytes chars.";
    char64  c64 = "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...";

    std::cout << "c16 = \"" << c16 << "\"." << std::endl;
    func< char64 >( c16 );
    std::cout << "c16 = \"" << c16 << "\"." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "c64 = \"" << c64 << "\"." << std::endl;
    func< char16 >( c64 );
    std::cout << "c64 = \"" << c64 << "\"." << std::endl;

    return  0;
}
```

Output:

```
> ./array_inner_type 
c16 = "16 bytes chars.".
func
-= source =-
->      Type is A64_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     64
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "fa37JncCHryDsbzayy4cBWDxS22JjzhMaiRrV41mtzxlYvKWrO72tK0LK0e1zLO".
-= target =-
->      Type is A16_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     16
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "16 bytes chars.".
c16 = "fa37JncCHryDsbza".
c64 = "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...".
func
-= source =-
->      Type is A16_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     16
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "Z2nOXpPIhMFSv8k".
-= target =-
->      Type is A64_c
->      Pointer size:   8
->      Number of elements:     64
->      Size of each element:   1
->      contents: "64 bytes chars. There's a lot more room here...".
c64 = "Z2nOXpPIhMFSv8k".
```

Sorry again, people...